Multiple graphs in one plot, with a variable in the plot range
I want to plot
$$y(z) = \dfrac{x^2}{2z}\left[1 + \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{2z}{x^2} \right)^2}\right]$$
where the range of $z$ is
$$0<z\leq \dfrac{x^2}{2}.$$
The thing is I want to do this for say, three different values of x. What I did is as follows:
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[(x^2/2 z) (1+ Sqrt[1-((2 z)/x^2)^2])/.{x->0.25}],{z,0.1,0.5 x^2}];  
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[(x^2/2 z) (1+ Sqrt[1-((2 z)/x^2)^2])/.{x->0.5}],{z,0.1,0.5 x^2}];
p3 =  Plot[Evaluate[(x^2/2 z) (1+ Sqrt[1-((2 z)/x^2)^2])/.{x->0.75}],{z,0.1,0.5 x^2}];
Show[p1,p2,p3]

What I would've wanted was to show all of them and have them color coded according to values of x. But the problem is it only shows p1 everytime.

You only make replacement for the x in the function, but not in the range of z. You would have to do something like this:
Plot[Evaluate[(x^2/2 z) (1 + Sqrt[1 - ((2 z)/x^2)^2]) /. {x -> 0.5}], 
     {z, 0, 0.5 x^2} /. {x -> 0.5}]

I suggest you make an auxiliary function for plotting, which will take x and color as arguments. Afterwards, combine all three plots with Show and set PlotRange -> Full to properly rescale the y axis:
plot[x_, color_] := Plot[(x^2/2 z) (1 + Sqrt[1 - ((2 z)/x^2)^2]), {z, 0, 0.5 x^2}, 
  PlotStyle -> color, PlotLegends -> {x}]

Show[plot[0.25, Orange], plot[0.5, Lighter[Orange, .3]], 
     plot[0.75, Lighter[Orange, .6]], PlotRange -> Full]



Thanks! An additional question, how do I do x= 0.25, x= 0.5, ... in the plotlegends part? I tried plotlegends -> {"x=0.25","x=0.5",...} and what happens is I get the color labels all with "x=0.25"

@jboy, try with PlotLegends -> {Row[{"x = ", x}]}.

First define x values and plot colors. I use indexed color scheme 97, which is the default plot coloring for Plot:
y[x_, z_] := (x^2/2 z) (1 + Sqrt[1 - ((2 z)/x^2)^2])

xVals = Range[0.25, 0.75, 0.25];
colors = ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range@Length@xVals;

Define the plotting function (this is essentially the same as in @Domen's answer)
createPlot[x_, color_] := 
 Plot[y[x, z], {z, 0, 0.5 x^2}, PlotStyle -> color, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {x}]

And MapThread and Show:
MapThread[createPlot, {xVals, colors}] // Show


